# ASP.net saving hidden divs state

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a hacked up drop down box which displays and hides certain divs.

```
<div id="dropDownMenu" onclick="showMenu();">Option 2
  <ul>
    <li onclick="showDiv('div1');">Option 1</li>
    <li onclick="showDiv('div2');">Option 2</li>
    <li onclick="showDiv('div3');">Option 3</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

This works perfectly fine, except when my asp form button is clicked it reloads the page to the default load view (show Option 2 and div2).  How do I make it so the combobox does not reset to default every time I click the asp form button?

**Edit:** Okay I was able to add the hidden field no problem but I've never used the clientID property.  Help me out?

html:

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="currentSelection" value="div2" runat="server" />
```

javascript:

```
document.getElementById('currentSelection').value=divName;
```

Then I want to add

```
showDiv(document.getElementById('currentSelection').value)
```

to the end of my button click.

Comment: "Option 2" a variable, on server post change that variable to reflect selected option.

Comment: @Emmanuel N if he uses ul and JS instead of select/option it will not be posted to the server.

Answer (score 2):

Add a HiddenField to the page and make the showMenu function write the value of the current option in it. Then in the button click event restore the state of the dropdown reading the value from the hidden field. Basically you need a literal where Option 2 is and set its value.

You will need to get the client ID of the HiddenField for use in the JS function. You either need to use the ClientID property or set the id mode of the control to static but keep in mind that this will cause problem if you render this template more than one time because there will be multiple DOM elements with the same id.